# SPD Workflow Trigger involving numbers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer-workflow

i created a SPD workflow. I want the workflow to only fire if a particular item contains any number (e.g. 84563).  If the item doesn't contain a number (e.g. it contains words or is blank) it won't fire.

I added the condition as:
If Current Item:*fieldname* contains 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

However this didn't prompt the workflow (in this case, sending an email) to fire when an entry had a number in the field.
Am I adding the condition correctly please? 
e.g. should it just be 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 without the commas, or maybe with ; between the numbers?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the workflow to start automatically when an item is created or modified?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SharePoint 2010 platform workflow in SharePoint Designer and type the condition as:

If Current Item:fieldname contains 0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9

[image]